# MySQL: Unable To Create Generated Column With Expression That Uses DATE_ADD() Function

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-8.0, computed-column

There might be a really obvious solution to my question, but I am stuck and did not manage find out what I am doing wrong, so you guys might tell me.

I am not able to create a nullable stored column for my expression using the DATE_ADD function in MySQL 8.

See the following example:

```sql
ADD COLUMN `test` TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE_ADD(col1, INTERVAL col2 HOUR)) STORED NULL;
```

col1 is TIMESTAMP and col2 is INT

MySQL does not complain, but just converts the expression to

```
(`col1` + interval `col2` hour)
```

And the resulting is not nullable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has done, what you ask of him.
here are [more infomration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)

DATE_ADD(col1, INTERVAL col2 HOUR) is equal to (`col1` + interval `col2` hour)

And is set as Default Value for the column. so when you add a NULL you get  what ever (`col1` + interval `col2` hour) represents.

So you can't achieve a Nullable and generated Column at the same time.

If You need A NULL there, you have to generate the test column VALUE at runtime.